# Simulate pinch to zoom with scroll wheel in MacOS

Tags: mac, keyboard, mouse, scrolling

I have a Macbook Pro that I use with an external keyboard and mouse. For the moue I am using a Logitech M705. I have noticed that in many applications I can not zoom with my scroll wheel. I think I have tried every single keyboard modifier combination but it won't seem to work. I've tried it in Logic Pro, Chrome, PreSonus Studio One.

I have better touch tools, but mapping `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`=` to a modifier and the scroll wheel has no effect in any application.

In other words, is there a way to simulate pinch to zoom with the scroll wheel?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @MarksCode No, I unfortunately, did not.

Answer (score 8):

I made [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org).

It lets you zoom in and out by scrolling while holding the Command (⌘) key. It works just like pinch-to-zoom on an Apple Trackpad.

It works great in Safari, Logic Pro, and everywhere else where pinch-to-zoom on an Apple Trackpad works.

On top of that it's open source, easy to use, 100% free, and it also has a bunch of other cool features that make your mouse better!

[Download](https://mousefix.org) | [GitHub](https://github.com/noah-nuebling/mac-mouse-fix)

Comment: Didn't work for me at all on Monterey with Logitech mx3s. Website version doesn't seem to offer this feature at all. Beta version offers it, but zoom doesn't work in Chrome no matter what key I map the modifier to.

Comment: Great app, works well with Logitech G102

Comment: Worked extremely well for me! Took me a bit of time (few minutes) to figure out how to use the app, but I got it set up just right now